# Advantage of OAuth vs HTTPS and SessionID

Tags: authentication, oauth, https, authorization, sessionid

What are the advantages are of using OAuth vs just using a sessionID + HTTPS? Seems like a lot of complexity for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth):

> It allows users to share their private resources (e.g. photos, videos, contact lists) stored on one site with another site without having to hand out their credentials, typically supplying username and password tokens instead. *Each token grants access to a specific site (e.g., a video editing site) for specific resources (e.g., just videos from a specific album) and for a defined duration (e.g., the next 2 hours). This allows a user to grant a third party site access to their information stored with another service provider, without sharing their access permissions or the full extent of their data*.